# Цикл if else до тех пор, пока

Tags: java, циклы, if

Есть класс Scan. В классе - статический метод returnScanner(), проверяющий является ли чисто введённое пользователем Integer.

Задача - заставить пользователя вводить из клавиатуры символы столько раз, пока он не введёт Integer

```
if (returnedScan != null){
        System.out.println("Program is finished. You wrote integer num: " +returnedScan );
    }else {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Let's try again");
        returnedScan = Scan.returnScanner();
    }
```

Такой цикл у меня работает только дважды, Как мне зациклить цикл, до тех пор, пока гарантированно не сработает if?

На всякий случай метод returnScanner()

```
static Integer returnScanner() {
    System.out.println("Please, enter the int number:");
    try {
        Integer scanner = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        System.out.println("WOW. You are genius!");
        return scanner;
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error! Not an integer");
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как насчёт `while` ?

```
while(expression){
// to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

```
private static void check(){
    Integer returnedScan = Scan.returnScanner();

    if (returnedScan != null){
        System.out.println("Program is finished. You wrote integer num: " +returnedScan );
    }else {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Let's try again");
        check();
    }
}`
```

Comment: Так делать неправильно. Используйте цикл do...while.